# jquery body css overflow-x not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, overflow

I want make a screen width judge, when screen width is `bigger than 1024px`, the body scroll bar will hidden, else when screen width is `smaller than 1024px` the body scroll bar will show its scroll.

See code in

> http://jsfiddle.net/xmJzU/   (overflow-x)
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/xmJzU/1/  (overflowX)

And test in

> http://jsfiddle.net/xmJzU/show
>
> http://jsfiddle.net/xmJzU/1/show

However when I dragged my browser edge, adjuce screen width smaller than 1024px, there have no scroll bar appear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, you just need to also declare the `width` variable inside your resize handler as the global variable is not in its' scope.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 1025) {
        $('body').css('overflow-x', 'scroll');
    } else {
        $('body').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
    }

    $(window).bind('resize', function() {
        var width = $(window).width();
        if (width < 1025) {
            $('body').css('overflow-x', 'scroll');
        } else {
            $('body').css('overflow-x', 'hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/xmJzU/2/)

An alternative method to using javascript for this is to use [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), but obviously this is dependant on the min-browser spec requirements you have.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this css:

```
body {
width:100%;
min-width:200px;
overflow-x:hidden;
}
```